# Getting Table Name in Cursor Results , Android, SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursoradapter, sql-except

I am writing an Android app involving cars and parts.

The thing I am seeking to do is offer a ListView of all the parts in the db excluding the parts already assigned for a specific car.

I am able to get the results I want with the following query with an EXCEPT statement in it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Parts._id, Parts.PartNumber, Parts.PartName,  Parts.MFG, Parts.Barcode, Parts.Notes, Parts.Photo
FROM Parts
JOIN CarsToParts
WHERE CarsToParts.CarID != carID
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT Parts._id, Parts.PartNumber, Parts.PartName,  Parts.MFG, Parts.Barcode, Parts.Notes, Parts.Photo
FROM Parts
JOIN CarsToParts
WHERE CarsToParts.CarID = carID AND CarsToParts.PartID = Parts._id
```

The problem I'm having is I'm getting a Cursor result that includes the table name as part of the key names as follows:

```
I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@39719c0
I/System.out: 0 {
I/System.out:    Parts._id=21
I/System.out:    Parts.Photo=<unprintable>
I/System.out:    Parts.PartName=Oil Filter
I/System.out:    Parts.PartNumber=116 354 733
I/System.out:    Parts.MFG=Mercedes Benz
I/System.out:    Parts.Barcode=254485880
I/System.out:    Parts.Notes=
I/System.out: }
I/System.out: <<<<<
```

When I try to send this to the CursorAdapter it chokes on it.

The CarsToParts table has the following columns:

```
_id
CarID
PartID
```

The CarsToParts table allows me to map the same part to two different cars, which is often a possibility with cars from the same manufacture.

**Is there a way to get SQLite to not include the table name as part of the key namesin the Cursor output?**

**EDIT:**
Upon further investigation I find CursorAdapter requires the *_id* column to be present. Which it is if only I can get SQLite to not include the table name as part of the key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names returned by a query [are unspecified](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html), unless you use AS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Parts._id AS _id, Parts.PartNumber AS PartNumber, ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. (thumbs up)